# SDK path is empty in Notepad++ plugin.net

Tags: c#, plugins, sdk, path, notepad++

I'm trying to develop a Notepad++ plugin using a nppPlugin.netV0.6 template.

Downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppPlugin.NET.v0.6.zip/download

I got a build error [`SDK path is empty.`]

The same template is working in other system (XP also).

Can anyone give me an resolution for this issue?

Comment: Where is a copy of the nppPlugin.net template that you are using?

Comment: @RyanGates Downloaded link updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The build process calls program `ildasm.exe`. The directory for that program may not have been added to the `PATH` environment variable. When I installed Visual Studio 2012 Express installer the directory was not added so I added it to the `PATH` and the build succeeded.

I tracked the problem down by increasing the amount of logging output written by the build process. (Via Tools => Options => Projects and Solutions => Build and run => MS Build ... verbosity.)

Not sure whether your error is identical. Before adding the directory to the `PATH` the errors below were generated:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: NppManagedPluginDemo.VS2010, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1> NppManagedPluginDemo.VS2010 -> C:\Adrian\VS\NppPlugin.NET.v0.5\Demo Plugin\NppManagedPluginDemo\bin\Debug\Demo.dll
1> ILDasm: calling 'ildasm.exe' with /quoteallnames /unicode /nobar /linenum "/out:C:\Users\Adrian_2\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpAB1F\Demo.il" "C:\Adrian\VS\NppPlugin.NET.v0.5\Demo Plugin\NppManagedPluginDemo\bin\Debug\Demo.dll"
1>C:\Adrian\VS\NppPlugin.NET.v0.5\Demo Plugin\NppManagedPluginDemo\DllExport\NppPlugin.DllExport.targets(8,5): error : The system cannot find the file specified
```

There are several versions of `ildasm.exe` in sub directories of `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\` of my current computer.